# How do you iterate over tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote some code like this that compiled fine:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args>
class Functions
{
    // stuff
public:
    Functions(Args... args)
    {
        tuple<decltype(args)...> t{args...}; 
        auto begin = begin(t);
        auto end = end(t);
        auto it = begin;
        while (it != end)
        {
             cout << *it;
        }
    }
};
```

Upon trying to use it though I can see that it doesn't actually work. Is there a way to iterate over a tuple using standard library functions?

Comment: I don't think so. What type is `*it` expression supposed to be, considering that tuple elements could be of different types? Generally, you need recursive template instantiation to iterate over a parameter pack - you need to "loop" at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: C++14 makes this easier.

Comment: Would a `for` loop with an index work for you, not your classic iterator, but will loop with the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways of doing that. One method I like can is using this neat template expansion trick:

```
auto l = {0, ((std::cout << args), 0)...};
(void)l;
```

The plus is that you don't need the tuple and its relatively short compared to other methods.

If you still need the tuple, you can use indicies to access the tuple elements by index:

```
template<int... Indices>
struct indices {
    typedef indices<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)> next;
};

template<int N>
struct build_indices {
    typedef typename build_indices<N - 1>::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct build_indices<0> {
    typedef indices<> type;
};

template<int n>
using build_indices_t = typename build_indices<n>::type;

template<typename... Args>
class Functions
{
public:
    Functions(Args... args)
        : Functions(std::make_tuple(args...),
                    build_indices_t<sizeof...(Args)>())
    { }
private:
    template<typename... Ts, int... Is>
    Functions(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup, indices<Is...>)
    {
        print(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
    }

    void print() { }

    template<class Head, class... Tail>
    void print(Head&& head, Tail&&... tail)
    { std::cout << head; print(tail...); }
};
```

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji The expression `std::cout << args` is simply being repeated for every argument in the pack (thanks to the placement of `...`). The first zero is for the condition where `args` is empty, and the second is to basically ignore whatever's being returned by `operator<<()` and replace it with `int`. `l` is therefore a `std::initializer_list<int>` with all values `0`. The cast to `void` is to avoid any warnings generated about an unused variable.

Comment: In C++14, you may replace `indices` stuff by `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`.

Comment: To avoid the warning, you may alternatively use `std::initializer_list<int>{((std::cout << args), 0)...};` without dummy variable (and in bonus, no need to use extra `0` for empty case) (but the include is required).